# Ctrl click ng-click open page in new tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Basically I want my app to open links in new tab/page when user holds down Ctrl (on linux windows), Cmd (on OSX). What is the way to go.

Note: I cannot get rid of ng-click. the application uses it various method calls within scope.

Comment: Don't use ng-click. Use regular links: `<a href="/somePath">click here</a>`.

Comment: sorry but all of application uses method calls to various methods in scope using ng-click

Comment: Then your link is not really a link navigating to another page, but simply a way to cause side-effects in your application. And it should thus not go to another page/tab.

Comment: in what element is the ng-click? in an `<a>` or could it be also something else, like `<div>` ?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

In HTML,

```
<div ng-click="gotoPageOrFunc($event)"></div>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.gotoPageOrFunc = function(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey==1){
        // Use windows.location or your link.
    }else{
        // Your actual functionalities.
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost, should be **$event** though: ng-click="gotoPageOrFunc(**$event**)"

Answer (score 0):

Use directive.

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('newtab', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function($scope, $elem) {
            var target = $elem.attr('target');

            $elem.on('click', function(e) {
                target = $elem.attr('target');
                $elem.attr('target', '_blank');
            });

            $elem.on('blur', function() {
                $elem.attr('target', target);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

// UPD

usage

```
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" class="newtab">xoxo<a/>
or
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" newtab>xoxo</a>
or
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" data-newtab>xoxo</a>
```

// UPD 2

```
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" 
   data-ng-click="myControllerMethod()" class="newtab">xoxo<a/>
or
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" 
   data-ng-click="myControllerMethod()" newtab>xoxo</a>
or
<a href="/my/page?foo=bar" 
   data-ng-click="myControllerMethod()" data-newtab>xoxo</a>
```

Comment: how to use this directive?

Comment: problem is i still need to call a controller method on click. I don't see that in the usage

Comment: This won't work because just as `myControllerMethod()` starts to evaluate, you've left the page, possibly terminating it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="getPreviousURL()" href="https://www.google.com/unlimited-plan/">More.../a>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getPreviousURL = function(moreurl,category,returnurl) {
var revrl=category+'bundles';
$window.localStorage.setItem('prev_url',revrl);
**var target = $elem.attr('href');**
**window.location = target;**
};
```